# Term for strong/weak words (in context)

Tags: word-usage

[Over in Mi Yodeya Meta](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/182), commenting on the proposed [Mi Yodeya site scope](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) —

> for people who base their lives on Jewish law and tradition and anyone interested in learning more

— I mentioned that "I'd replace *people* with *those*". When pressed for a reason, I said:

> Because (and I don't know the words to explain this right, so bear with me) *those* is less strong a word. *People* calls more attention to itself, is more noticeable, and, therefore, pulls more attention away from the more important part of the line. At least, that's my impression.

That is, when you're reading that line, your eye/mind is more likely to skip over *those* without the word making an impression than over *people*. Skipping over it is a good thing in this case, since it's not the semantically important part of the line.

You may not, of course, agree with me on that score, but my question is: How should I have described this? Is there a term that style sheets or grammarians or English teachers or linguists or whoever use for such 'strong' words-in-context?

Comment: I don't see the difference at all in any terms that could be associated with strength or directness. 'People' is slightly more definite than 'those', the latter being a pronoun whose referent happens not to be mentioned yet. It's a minimal stylistic variation that you really shouldn't worry about. If you would say it one way rather than another then, great, thats up to when you write things.

Comment: Mitch, I didn't mention directness, but what I was trying to get at... hang on, lemme edit the question.

Comment: All: This question needs tagging help, please.

Comment: This is really vague. It might conceivably have some named concept associated with it, but we don't have enough examples or explanation to go on other than your 'feeling'. Sometimes questions like this get lucky and happen to have a corresponding exact concept and label, but so far, this doesn't seem to have one.

Comment: @Mitch - maybe not an **exact** concept or label, but maybe we can help OP find a **better** way to express that concept.  I'm not saying that you've done this, but in general, I've seen a number of questions in the few months of my membership where a comment was made that "no single word exists" but through the synergy of our community, a word or phrase was produced that satisfied the OP.

Comment: @Mitch: The concept of "strength" of a word is related to how much meaning it conveys. This is apparent e.g. in the rule "avoid adverbs" - *he moved slowly and carefully* is better expressed as *he edged* - "to edge" is a stronger verb than "to move". Similarly with nouns, "a pleasant smell like perfume or flowers" is better expressed as "fragrance", a stronger noun. Pronouns are inherently weaker than nouns.

Comment: @SF: so you're saying 'stronger' is better?

Comment: @Mitch: Here, yes. One of these articles was comparing pulp fiction novels (example dripping with adverbs, often more than one per sentence) to fiction by esteemed authors (Tolkien, Pratchett) using a rich vocabulary of strong nouns and verbs, with less than one adverb per page. And all of these articles said "stronger" is better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right. Nouns of any sort are much stronger than pronouns.

There are thousands and thousands of nouns, so each carries a lot of meaning, to use the Conduit Metaphor. There are only a few pronouns, however, because they don't have any intrinsic meaning, only type codings -- demonstrative, masculine, plural, whatever.

This is what pronouns are for -- to substitute for nouns by leaving an id marker, thereby not requiring us to identify somebody again. That's why pronouns are unstressed and often reduced by loss of (for instance) the /h/ in /hi/: /ɪzi'ðɛɹ/ 'Is he there?'; or the /y/ in /ay/: /amənə'gonaw/ 'I'm going to go now'.

What one wants in a pronoun (as I said in [an article about "singular *they*"](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/June05Eye.pdf)) is

> "... a word that readers can zip over rapidly, with just enough referentiality to point to the proper individual without distracting anyone from what the writer wants them to be thinking about. That’s why we use pronouns instead of full descriptions in the first place."

Comment: +1, many thanks. But did you mean _ego_ rather than _id_?

Comment: Also: you used _stronger_, which I'd used in the question. Should I infer that it's your adjective of choice for this phenomenon?

Comment: @msh210: Oh, I meant /ay'di/, i.e, ID, _identification_; like a URL. Sorry. As for _strong_, it's a metaphor and not my favorite, no; linguists talk about "semantic bleaching", a process where a meaningful word is used as an auxiliary or marker so often that it loses its meaning. _Have_ is a good example; it only means _possess_ a small proportion of the times it appears. But any construction with a pronoun will be more easily interpreted than one with a noun, other things being equal, just because it parses easier.

Comment: I've searched quite a few articles about adverb abuse in fiction writing, trying to find out why they are considered evil. Every single of them talked about using "strong verbs" instead.

Comment: Oh, that's just more [Strunk and White nonsense](http://chronicle.com/article/50-Years-of-Stupid-Grammar/25497). Pay no attention to the passive [peevers](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/grammar/prescrip.html); they [literally](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/grammar/passives.html) don't know what they're talking about.

Comment: @John: which S&W nonsense? The strong is better than weak or the active is better than passive?

Comment: No, _strong_ is intrinsically preferable to _weak_; that's part of the metaphor. The nonsense is that _strong_ and _weak_ are useful terms in speaking of semantics. There are clines of emotional strength: "Fuck you!" is much stronger than "Oh, my." But that's not what S&W meant; they meant "use the words we'd like you to" without specifying what they were. And, as for "passive", they totally confused the passive grammatical construction with emotional passivity, which is just ignorant. Most of the sentences they called passive aren't. And they violate all their rules.

Comment: Other than that, though, no worries.

Answer (score 2):

You're right that "people" calls attention to itself, and that the pronoun works in this case in a supporting role, serving to let "Jewish law and tradition" be the most important part of the sentence. Pronouns are by definition less assertive than nouns, requiring some referent, whether explicit or implied.

If someone says "John is here, " you know who is here; if they say "He is here, " you have to ask "Who?" unless you already know.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you mean - ***"people"***, in your view and in that context, could be considered more ***"direct"*** than if you rephrased it to say, per your example:

> for ***"those"*** who base their lives on Jewish law and tradition and anyone interested in learning more

While ***"directness"*** is good for avoiding ambiguousness, it can also be seen as a bit ***"assertive"*** or too ***""in your face""***.